# Find general solution to the non-homogeneous equation: $y'' - 16y' + 64y = \frac{e^{-8x}}{1 + x^2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, initial-value-problems, homogeneous-equation

Find the most general solution to the non-homogeneous equation:

$$y'' - 16y' + 64y = \frac{e^{-8x}}{1 + x^2}$$

With the given conditions: $y(0) = -10$ and $y'(0) = 9$. I partially solved it, with

$$e^{8x} \int_0^x \frac{-te^{-16t}}{1+t^2}dt + xe^{8x} \int_0^x \frac{-e^{-16t}}{1+t^2}dt + Ce^{8x}+Dxe^{8x}$$

I am not sure what the variables C and D are. Can anyone help me find the variables?

Comment: Please format your math with MathJax. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is extremely complicated to read your work in the problem. You have a differential equations of the form $y"+\color{red}{b}y'+\color{red}{c}y=\color{blue}{r(x)}$ which is a $\color{blue}{\text{non-homogenous}}$ ordinary differential equations with $\color{red}{\text{constant coefficients}}$, so you can use for example indeterminate coefficients methods or parameter variations.

Comment: Apply the inital conditions to find $C$ and $D$

Comment: When I calculated it, $C = -10$ and $D = 88$. The software that is grading it says it's wrong.

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't say.

Comment: Nevermind. I solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$ (ye^{-8x})''=(y''-16y'+64y)e^{-8x}$$
and hence the equation becomes
$$ (ye^{-8x})''=\frac{e^{−16x}}{1+x^{2}}. $$
So
$$ (ye^{-8x})'=\int_0^x\frac{e^{−16t}}{1+t^{2}}dt+C $$
and hence
$$ ye^{-8x}+10=\int_0^x\int_0^s\frac{e^{−16t}}{1+t^{2}}dtds+Cx=\int_0^x\int_t^x\frac{e^{−16t}}{1+t^{2}}dsdt+Cx=\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)e^{−16t}}{1+t^{2}}dsdt+Cx. $$
So
$$ y=e^{8x}\bigg[-10+\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)e^{−16t}}{1+t^{2}}dt+Cx\bigg]. $$
Now
\begin{eqnarray}
y'&=&8e^{8x}\bigg[-10+\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)e^{−16t}}{1+t^{2}}dt+Cx\bigg]\\
&& +e^{8x}\bigg[\int_0^x\frac{e^{−16t}}{1+t^{2}}dt+C\bigg]
\end{eqnarray}
and using $y'(0)=9$, one has
$$ 8(-10)+C=9 $$
which implies $C=89$. So the solution is
$$ y=e^{8x}\bigg[-10+\int_0^x\frac{(x-t)e^{−16t}}{1+t^{2}}dt+89x\bigg]. $$

Answer (score 0):

OK, same guy here. I found out how to solve it:

$y"−16y′+64y=(e^{−8x})/(1+x^{2})$

And given the initial conditions y(0) = -10 and y'(0) = 9

To find C and D, we just make the left half of the equation equal 0 and solve it.

$y"−16y′+64y=0$

The general formula for the solution is:

$y = Ae^{8x}+Bxe^{8x}$ and $y' = 8Axe^{8x}+Ae^{8x}+Be^{8x}$

Applying the initial values into both formulas will give you:

A = 89 and B = -10

These coefficients are the same as D and C respectively.